# How to send the output of this command: find ./ -type f -exec grep -H 'String' {} \; to a file?

Tags: unix, logging, grep, find

Somewhere in here someone shared this cool way to find stuff in unix:

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep -H 'string to be searched' {} \;
```

And I was wondering how to send the output of it to a file.

I tried the basic `>> something.log` but it seems to ignore it, perhaps because of the last part of the command `{} \;`

Could you help me to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/how-can-i-grep-the-results-of-find-using-exec-and-still-output-to-a-file

Comment: Could you please share with us what happens when you execute the command with the output sending to the file.

Comment: For future reference .. `>` will completely overwrite a file with your output --  `>>` simply appends to the file you are writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu, it works perfectly using the standard way you mentioned, just write the command as following:

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep -H 'string to be searched' {} \; > newFile.txt
```